# Is there any need to unit test merged C# assemblies before and after merging using SmartAssembly?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, merge, smartassembly

I have two C# DLLs: *Main.dll* and *Pudding.dll*.
I also have unit tests that cover the behaviour and interfaces of *Main.dll*.

When I ship *Main.dll* I want to merge *Pudding.dll* into it, so that users only have one file to handle (and other awesome reasons). I use [SmartAssembly](https://www.red-gate.com/) to do the merge.

Before merging I run the unit tests to ensure *Main.dll* behaves and has the interfaces it should.

However following merging of the files, should I then test again, is it worth it? Has anything actually changed in *Main.dll* apart from shoving *Pudding.dll* inside it?

Does anyone know?
Ta.

Comment: I would contact RedGate support with this question. Just to be on the safe side, in the event of no definitive answer from RedGate, I would re-run the unit tests.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, merging via SmartAssembly 6 alters *Main.dll* and you should re-run tests.

Information on a SmartAssemblies support [page](https://documentation.red-gate.com/sa6/obfuscating-your-code-with-smartassembly/merging-dependencies) shows that changes are made at a code level to *Main.dll*. And changes to the code *could* have an impact on *Main.dll* and its behaviour and interface.

And *could*, IMHO, is a good enough reason to test again (because you never know what mad-reverse-engineered-reflection-based-text-lookup-magictext code someone else may have added).

:)